# prove $\left( \begin{array}{c} 2n \\ n\ \end{array} \right) = 2 \left( \begin{array}{c} n \\ 2\ \end{array} \right) + n^2$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I came across the following proof in my textbook that was used as a end of chapter review. How can I prove the following algebraically?

$$\left( \begin{array}{c} 2n \\ n\ \end{array} \right) = 2 \left( \begin{array}{c} n \\ 2\ \end{array} \right) + n^2$$

Comment: Is there a typo? I don't think that's true

Comment: n=1 is false?! Isn't it?

Comment: Left hand side should be $\left( \begin{array}{c} 2n \\ 2\ \end{array} \right)$ I think.

Comment: FWIW, $\binom{2n}{n}\geq \frac{4^{n}}{2n+1},$ so if that is what the book said, it is way off base because the left side increases exponentially, while the right side does not.

Comment: yes sorry that was a typo!

Comment: Please make the intended edit to correct your Question.  Until corrected, Readers must guess at what your problem is.

Comment: @user104 Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative, with the typo correction we have

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{2n}{2} = 2 \binom{n}{2}+n^2
\end{eqnarray*}$$

which can be interpreted in this way

- LHS is the number of couples we can choose among $2n$
- RHS is the same choice mabe by dividing in two groups of n; indeed we can choose $\binom{n}{2}$ couples from the first group + $\binom{n}{2}$ couples from the second group and then the couples made of 1 from the first group and 1 from the second that is $n\cdot n=n^2$

Comment: is this a complete proof?

Comment: would this be considered a algebraic proof or combinatorial?

Comment: It is combinatorial of course, I’ve given it as an interesting alternative

Comment: okay this makes sense as a complete combinatorial proof, thanks!

Comment: Maybe of interest:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2533960/combinatorical-proof-of-the-identity-binom2n2-2-binomn2n2/2534089

Comment: @PeterSzilas Thanks Peter!

Answer (score 6):

Typo alert
\begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{2n}{\color{red}{2}} = 2 \binom{n}{2}+n^2.
\end{eqnarray*}

Now use $\binom{n}{2} =\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ and the above formula is easy to prove.

Comment: thanks that was a typo, could you show me how to use that formula? I haven't seen it before

Comment: would this be considered a algebraic proof or combinatorial?

Comment: Yes, this is an algebriac proof ... still trying to think of a nice combinatorial arguement that demonstrates the formula ...

Comment: how do I use that formula you gave? that would conclude the algebraic proof

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{2n}{2} = \frac{ 2n(2n-1)}{2} = \cdots
\end{eqnarray*}
and now see DrSG's solution.

Comment: $$2n(2n-1)=n(n-1)+n^2 $$ would this complete it?

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
\cdots = 2\frac{ n(n-1)}{2} +n^2 = 2 \binom{n}{2} +n^2.
\end{eqnarray*}
yes & this completes the proof.

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{2n}{\color{red}{2}} = 2 \binom{n}{2}+n^2.
\end{eqnarray*}

using $\binom{n}{2} =\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$,

\begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{2n}{\color{red}{2}} = \frac{2n(2n-1)}{2} =  2n(n-1) = 2 \cdot\frac{n(n-1)}{2} + n^2 = 2 \binom{n}{2}+n^2  
\end{eqnarray*}